# How to use array_agg() aggregate function in pig or hive

Tags: python, hive, apache-pig, aggregate-functions, array-agg

I have the below data:

```
================================================================
session_id                       screen_name  screen_launch_time
================================================================
990004916946605-1404157897784    screen1      1404157898275
990004916946605-1404157897784    screen2      1404157898337
990004947764274-1435162269418    screen1      1435162274044
990004947764274-1435162269418    screen3      1435162274081
```

I would like to use an `array_agg` function to get my data in the below format:

```
=========================================================
session_id                      screen_flow         count
=========================================================
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen1->screen2    1
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen1->screen3    1
```

Has anyone tried writing a `UDAF` or `python` script to implement the logic used in an `array_agg` function?

Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: Hive has a built in `collect_set()` and `collect_list()` which aggregates items to an array.  There is a udf here that does the same https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect

Comment: Hi, it gives me this error:

Comment: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 character '' not supported here

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do because you asked a very generic question with zero code.  If you need help with code, it would be beneficial to post said code and re-state your problem in a more specific manner.

Comment: I have a table with columns -[ session_id string, screens string, screen_launch_time bigint]
sample values:

Comment: I have a table with columns -[ session_id string, screens string, screen_launch_time bigint]
sample values:
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen1      1404157898275
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen2      1404157898337
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen1      1435162274044
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen3      1435162274081

Comment: Now, I want to have the above data in below format:
session                                                  screen_flow            count
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen1->screen2     1 (this count is for all the sessions having the same screen flow)
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen1->screen3     1 (this count is for all the sessions having the same screen flow)

Do I make sense now :) ?

Comment: You need to hit `edit` and type all that into your question.

Comment: I added in my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just group by the `session_id`, concat `screen_name`, and count the records per group.  If you don't want to build the [brickhouse](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse) jar, you can use `collect_list()` instead of `collect()` (but I don't recommend it).

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
create temporary function collect as "brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF";

select session_id, screen_flow
  , count(*) count
from (
  select session_id
    , concat_ws('->', collect(screen_name)) screen_flow
  from db.table
  group by session_id ) x
group by session_id, screen_flow
```

**Output**:

```
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen1->screen2    1
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen1->screen3    1
```

Comment: Good one GoBrewers.. I also need to do 2 other things: 1. remove duplicate screens (if any) after grouping by session id 2. rank them based on max counts. Can you help on this?

Comment: If my answer solves your original problem, mark as correct and then if you have additional questions, ask a new question and I will certainly help if I can.

Comment: hi GoBrewers, here is the link for new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681157/how-to-find-the-pathing-flow-and-rank-them-using-pig-or-hive

Comment: I would love to hear the reasoning as to why my answer wasn't marked as correct, especially after the effort I put into helping you on this question.

Comment: Your answer was correct GoBrewer, I clicked on the tick mark.. Is there a different way to mark it as correct ?

Comment: GoBrewer, this is my first attempt to post question, so help me understand how to mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: GoBrewer, did you get my reply?

Comment: GoBrewer, any thoughts on how we can remove subsequent screen names if they are same and ranking? I'm impressed with your approach and Your hlep is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Input :-

```
990004916946605-1404157897784,screen1,1404157898275
990004916946605-1404157897784,screen2,1404157898337
990004947764274-1435162269418,screen1,1435162274044
990004947764274-1435162269418,screen3,1435162274081
```

Below is answer in Pig Style..

```
records = LOAD '/user/user/inputfiles/session_id.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (session_id:chararray,screen_name:chararray,screnn_launch_time:chararray);

rec_grped = GROUP records BY session_id;

rec_each =  FOREACH rec_grped 
                     {
                       rec_inner_each = FOREACH records GENERATE screen_name;

                       GENERATE group as session_id, REPLACE(BagToString(rec_inner_each),'_','-->') as screen_flow, 1 as cnt;
};

dump rec_each;
```

output :-

```
990004916946605-1404157897784   screen1-->screen2    1
990004947764274-1435162269418   screen1-->screen3    1
```

Comment: Thanks Surender. Good one. I also need to do 2 other things: 1. remove duplicate screens (if any) after grouping by session id 2. rank them based on max counts. Can you help on this?

Comment: Ok.. For duplicate scenario, just give me input and expected output.. Also it would be good if you ask it as a separate question..thanks

Comment: Hi Surender, I have posted it as a separate question -

Comment: link for the separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681157/how-to-find-the-pathing-flow-and-rank-them-using-pig-or-hive

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Grouping to a bag doesn't preserve order.

Comment: @GoBrewers I executed that code above,It s been tested and it gives the above pasted output .Could you explain little detail about the issue

Comment: When u group and create a bag, its contents may (but will not necessarily) be in order.  So this code works on this toy example but could potentially produce incorrect output.  As in you could have a scenario where the user went `screen1 -> screen2` but the bag rearranges then and it spits out `screen2 -> screen1`.  This is incorrect.  My solution uses a UDF that preserves the order of the items being collected.

Comment: Correct, I Will try to fix this in another question posted by same user

Comment: Good catch GoBrewer :)

Comment: @SurenderRaja will you be able to help me with a pig script for the hive query given by go brewer in below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681157/how-to-find-the-pathing-flow-and-rank-them-using-pig-or-hive/32699912#32699912

Comment: @SurenderRaja - Will you be able to help me with a pig script for the hive query given by go brewer in below link pls ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681157/how-to-find-the-pathing-flow-and-rank-them-using-pig-or-hive/32699912#32699912

Comment: @Surender Raja - did you have a chance to see my comment?

Comment: just 5 mins.. but I cannot produce the result  in pig without JAVA UDF. I will give you solution Pig with JAVA UDF