# how to find the pathing flow and rank them using pig or hive?

Tags: python, hive, apache-pig, aggregate-functions, dense-rank

Below is the example for my use case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok.. I got the requirement.. Tried for some time to get the actual output.. looks like we need a java UDF to remove adjacent same screen names.. let me think for some more time on this. I would like to give a solution without UDF

Comment: @explorethis : Is it possible to add the input and expected output in plain text format ?  I like to try this use case.

Comment: @MuraliRao : I couldn't format in the same order. It puts as a plain text. If you can share your email, I will send in a word doc for this :)

Comment: @Surender Raja - Can you give me suggestion on below scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768964/mobile-application-churn-rate-calculation-using-pig-or-hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324764/hadoop-hive-collect-list-without-repeating-items/31330778#31330778) where an OP was asking something similar.  If I am understanding your problem correctly, you want to remove duplicates from the path, but only when they occur next to each other.  So `1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1` would become `1 -> 2 -> 1`.  If this is correct, then you can't just group and `distinct` (as I'm sure you have noticed) because it will remove *all* duplicates.  An easy solution is to write a UDF to remove those duplicates while preserving the distinct path of the user.

**UDF**:

```
package something;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

public class RemoveSequentialDuplicatesUDF extends UDF {
    public ArrayList<Text> evaluate(ArrayList<Text> arr) {
        ArrayList<Text> newList = new ArrayList<Text>();
        newList.add(arr.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {

            String front = arr.get(i).toString();
            String back  = arr.get(i-1).toString();

            if (!back.equals(front)) {
                newList.add(arr.get(i));
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

To build this jar you will need a `hive-core.jar` and `hadoop-core.jar`, you can find these here in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/).  Make sure you get the version of Hive and Hadoop that you are using in your environment.  Also, if you plan to run this in a production environment, I'd suggest adding some exception handling to the UDF.  After the jar is built, import it and run this query:

**Query**:

```
add jar /path/to/jars/brickhouse-0.7.1.jar;
add jar /path/to/jars/hive_common-SNAPSHOT.jar;
create temporary function collect as "brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF";
create temporary function remove_dups as "something.RemoveSequentialDuplicatesUDF";

select screen_flow, count
  , dense_rank() over (order by count desc) rank
from (
  select screen_flow
    , count(*) count
  from (
    select session_id
      , concat_ws("->", remove_dups(screen_array)) screen_flow
    from (
      select session_id
        , collect(screen_name) screen_array
      from (
        select *
        from database.table
        order by screen_launch_time ) a
      group by session_id ) b
    ) c
  group by screen_flow ) d
```

**Output**:

```
s1->s2->s3      2       1
s1->s2          1       2
s1->s2->s3->s1  1       2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Geat!! I'm going to try this and will let you know :) With what I see, I understood your approach and hopefully will solve my problem.

Comment: Awesome!! It woks perfect. Appreciate it GoBrewer

Comment: I need your expertise to solve the problem posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768964/mobile-application-churn-rate-calculation-using-pig-or-hive

Comment: any thoughts on my new post in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768964/mobile-application-churn-rate-calculation-using-pig-or-hive

Comment: Will you be able to rewrite the above hive logic using pig?

Comment: @Surender Raja - Will you be able to help me with a pig script for the above hive query written by GoBrewer pls?

Comment: any thoughts on how we can approach for question in link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768964/mobile-application-churn-rate-calculation-using-pig-or-hive

Comment: I already upvote for your post. You should see your points. Is there something I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
990004916946605-1404157897784,S1,1404157898275
990004916946605-1404157897784,S1,1404157898286
990004916946605-1404157897784,S2,1404157898337
990004947764274-1435162269418,S1,1435162274044
990004947764274-1435162269418,S2,1435162274057
990004947764274-1435162269418,S3,1435162274081
990004947764274-1435162287965,S2,1435162690002
990004947764274-1435162287965,S1,1435162690001
990004947764274-1435162287965,S3,1435162690003
990004947764274-1435162287965,S1,1435162690004
990004947764274-1435162212345,S1,1435168768574
990004947764274-1435162212345,S2,1435168768585
990004947764274-1435162212345,S3,1435168768593


register /home/cloudera/jar/ScreenFilter.jar;

screen_records =  LOAD '/user/cloudera/inputfiles/screen.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(session_id:chararray,screen_name:chararray,launch_time:long);

screen_rec_order =  ORDER screen_records  by launch_time ASC;

session_grped = GROUP screen_rec_order BY session_id;

eached = FOREACH session_grped
                      {
                         ordered = ORDER screen_rec_order by launch_time;

                        GENERATE group as session_id, REPLACE(BagToString(ordered.screen_name),'_','-->') as screen_str;

                      };

screen_each  =  FOREACH eached GENERATE session_id, GetOrderedScreen(screen_str) as screen_pattern;

screen_grp   = GROUP screen_each by screen_pattern;

screen_final_each = FOREACH screen_grp GENERATE group as screen_pattern, COUNT(screen_each) as pattern_cnt;

ranker = RANK screen_final_each BY pattern_cnt DESC DENSE;

output_data = FOREACH ranker GENERATE screen_pattern, pattern_cnt, $0 as rank_value;

dump output_data;
```

I am not able to find a way to use Pig Builtin function to remove adjacent screens for a same session_id ,hence I have used JAVA UDF inorder to remove the adjacent screen names.

I created a JAVA UDF called GetOrderedScreen and covrerted that UDF in to jar and named that jar as ScreenFilter.jar and  registered that jar in this Pig Script

Below is the Code for that GetOrderedScreen Java UDF

```
public class GetOrderedScreen extends EvalFunc<String> {


@Override
public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {


    String incoming_screen_str= (String)input.get(0);
    String outgoing_screen_str ="";
    String screen_array[] =incoming_screen_str.split("-->");

    String full_screen=screen_array[0];

  for (int i=0; i<screen_array.length;i++)
  {
     String prefix_screen=  screen_array[i];
     String suffix_screen="";
     int j=i+1;

     if(j< screen_array.length)
     {
         suffix_screen  = screen_array[j];
     }


 if (!prefix_screen.equalsIgnoreCase(suffix_screen))
     {
     full_screen = full_screen+ "-->" +suffix_screen;
     }

  }
  outgoing_screen_str =full_screen.substring(0, full_screen.lastIndexOf("-->")); 


  return outgoing_screen_str;

}
```

}

Output

```
(S1-->S2-->S3,2,1)
(S1-->S2,1,2)
(S1-->S2-->S3-->S1,1,2)
```

Hope this helps you!.. Also Wait for some more time, Some good brains who see this Question will answer effectively(without JAVA UDF)

Comment: awesome!! let me try this out.

Comment: One small question..Similar like rank, I need levels too..how to find the levels from above output?                                    for e.g. (S1-->S2-->S3 is level 2)
(S1-->S2 is level 1)
(S1-->S2-->S3-->S1 is level 3)..Basically counting the number of arrows (-->) .. Can you help with this?

Comment: I wrote a python script to count the substring to achieve the results. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Im now trying to add in two new columns application_name and date to the above pig script but facing troubles doing it. Can you help with this?

Comment: What is your application name and date.. Do you want to keep  it same for all output records

Comment: Application name varies ( app1 , app2 etc) and date field to know what day the particular path is for

Comment: I have the application name and date coming in from source itself

Comment: do you have a chance to look at my question?

Comment: Any help that you can provide me?

Comment: I need to iterate the above sample pig script over all date combinations by hardcoding start date as a particular date and end date will be system date.  Do you know if this can be achieved thru shell scripting?